# Regular expression that matches number or 100%, but not 99%

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regexp which matches on two groups of digits or 100% separated with 'x' char. Like (first group)x(second group). And "100%" should be captured as is, with percent symbol. And percent sign is allowed only after 100.

For example:

```
100x100 - OK
100%x100 - OK
99x99 - OK
99%x100 - not OK
99x99% - not OK
```

Here is my approach:

```
s = '100%x99%' # this should be failed
match = re.match(r'(100%|\d+(?!%))x(100%|\d+(?!%))', s)
if match:
  x = match.group(1)
  y = match.group(2)
```

I expect that y will be none and match would be failed, because '99%' is prohibited. But with my regexp I get `x = 100%` and `y = 9`.

How can I fix my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` after the last `\d+` to make sure it is not part of a longer match:

[`(100%|\d+(?!%))x(100%|\d+\b(?!%))`](https://regex101.com/r/yizEBh/1)

Answer (score 2):

This would work: `(\d+x\d+$)|(100%x\d+$)|(\d+x100%)`

This includes the case where `100%` could come after the `x` so if that's not the case, just remove that last group.

Answer (score 2):

```
(100%|\d+)x(100%|\d+)$
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/TtFg8V/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The other answers do work, but I would trim off the seemingly unnecessary parts to give the following:

```
(100%|\d+)x(100%|(\d+(?!\%|\d)))
```

This also does not require end lines with `$`. You can see it working [here](https://regex101.com/r/rfpW8a/1).